# Royalty free action music

Tags: music, royalty-free

I'm currently looking for some music for my action/shootout sequences in a video. Is there a website (other than incompetech.com) that has a good collection? Many websites I searched have an audio watermark.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this one on digitalproduction website. There are 100 cinematic tracks for free unlimited usage with proper credit. After download i found all files without the watermark and download was free for all.

https://www.909music.com/free-music

Answer (score 0):

There is some good quality music licensed through creative commons at https://musopen.org/